# could not execute statement; SQL [n/a] Caused by - Unknown column 'postback_data' in 'field list'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am Currently working on one of the requirements where I wanted to POST some data in my database.

In mys database named **template_data** I have three columns called **id**,**json_data** & **timestamp**. The json_data column will hold the json where the json values will be coming from the user such as:

```
        "suggestions": [
            {
                "reply": {
                    "text": "**Tobe given by user**",
                    "postbackData": "**Tobe given by user**"
                }
            }
```

I have to construct this JSON through my code what I am doing here in the below code

```
package com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.controller;


import com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.entity.TemplateData;
import com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.service.TemplateServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/templates")
public class TemplateController {

    private TemplateServiceImpl templateService;

    @Autowired
    public  TemplateController(TemplateServiceImpl theTemplateService){
        templateService = theTemplateService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("template", new TemplateData());
        return "templates/template-form"; // Thymeleaf template file name (e.g., template-form.html)
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listTemplateData(Model theModel) {

        List<TemplateData> theTemplateList =templateService.findAll();

        // add to the spring model
        theModel.addAttribute("templates", theTemplateList);

        return "templates/list-templates";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveData(@ModelAttribute("template") TemplateData template) {
        // Construct the complete JSON structure using user input
        String jsonData = "{\"suggestions\": [{" +
                "\"reply\": {" +
                "\"text\": \"" + template.getText() + "\"," +
                "\"postbackData\": \"" + template.getPostbackData() + "\"" +
                "}}]}";

        // Set timestamp
        template.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        // Save the complete JSON data to the database
        template.setJsonData(jsonData);

        templateService.saveData(template);

        return "redirect:/templates/list";

        //return "redirect:/success"; // Redirect to a success page
    }
}
```

**The service**

```
package com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.service;

import com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.dao.TemplateDataRepository;
import com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.entity.TemplateData;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TemplateServiceImpl implements TemplateService{

    private final TemplateDataRepository templateDataRepository;

    @Autowired
    public TemplateServiceImpl(TemplateDataRepository templateDataRepository) {
        this.templateDataRepository = templateDataRepository;
    }
    @Override
    public List<TemplateData> findAll() {
        return templateDataRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveData(TemplateData templateData) {
        //TemplateData templateData = new TemplateData();
        templateData.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        templateDataRepository.save(templateData);

    }



}
```

**The Repository (DAO)**

```
package com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.dao;

import com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.entity.TemplateData;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TemplateDataRepository extends JpaRepository<TemplateData, Integer> {
}
```

**My entity class holds below parameters**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="template_data")
public class TemplateData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="json_data")
    private String jsonData;

    @Column(name="timestamp")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    private String text;
    private String postbackData;
```

When I am trying to save this data using **/templates/save** api it is throwing the error below:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:232)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:243)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy111.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.service.TemplateServiceImpl.saveData(TemplateServiceImpl.java:29)
    at com.airkommtemplate.springboot.RCMTemplate.controller.TemplateController.saveData(TemplateController.java:59).......


Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'postback_data' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122......
```

I have tried changing the parameters of template type which I am passing in my controllers to service call, but nothing is working out.
Nothing is working out here, Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming "private String postbackData" is the culprit. Try annotating it with "@Transient" and see if it works. On a side note, I'd avoid mixing persisted and non-persisted data in a single class. Instead, have one pure Java class with no annotations, and another one just for persistence that is annotated.

Comment: It looks like the column name is called, `postback_data`.  Try adding `@Column(name="postback_data")` to your `postbackData` property.

Comment: I'll start following the comment of @lane.maxwell. Do you have set the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy` inside your application.properties/yml?

Comment: @lane.maxwell & @fforfabio Thanks for the replies, The first coment by @snajdov was really working for me I just have added @Transient annotation to the postbakdata and text fields and it is running fine for me as expected. When I tried to add ```@Column(name="postback_data")``` and ```@Transient``` both annotation it is also working but removing ```@Transient``` annotation is leading to the same error.

It would be great if someone can take step and clear me the basic idea of ```@Transient``` annotation.

Comment: @ShobhitSolanki You can think of the `@Transient` annotation as saying, "Don't map this field to a database column."  Regarding entities, you would generally only mark fields as Transient that you have defined a getter for that does some calculation.  For instance, if you have two fields named `subtotal` and `tax`, you would define a third field named `total` and mark it as Transient and create a method named getTotal that returns `subtotal + total;`.  The `total` field isn't anywhere in your schema, but is present in your entity as a calculated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind that

Java's transient keyword is used to denote that a field is not to be serialized, whereas JPA's @Transient annotation is used to indicate that a field is not to be persisted in the database, i.e. their semantics are different.

So please make the following changes

```
    @Transient
    private String text;

    @Transient
    private String postbackData;
```

Please accept the answer if it works, Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).